# What is the longest string I can have?

Tags: perl

Recently, I was asked in an interview question to reverse a string in perl. I wrote the code and they wanted me to give some example strings to test it. I gave them examples like a string with few characters, lot of characters, invalid characters etc etc. But they also asked what is the longest string I will test with.  I was not sure what to tell. 
Hence this question. 
What is the longest string I can test in a perl code ? What does it depend on ? Memory on the machine ?
Is there any limitation from perl stand point ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was looking to see if I can find any official documentation on the longest string. I found one at [http://perltutorial.org](http://www.perltutorial.org/perl-scalar-variables.aspx) talking about Strings:

> Perl defines string as a sequence of characters. The shortest string contains no character or null string. ***The longest string can contain unlimited characters which is only limited to available memory of your computer.***

I don't know if this is *official* enough for you. It'd be nice to see something in the FAQ or Perldoc.

By the way, to officially reverse a string in Perl:

```
my $rev_string = reverse $string;
```

This is in the Perl FAQ #4 which has a bunch of string handling stuff in it. The *reverse a string* question is an old trick interview question to see if someone knows their arcane Perl stuff. Sure almost everyone knows `reverse` will reverse an array, but do they also know it will reverse a string? *Noobies* will work out some sort of complex algorithm and the interviewer will have a reason to feel smug and not hire that person.

Personally, if I was interviewing someone, I asked this question, and someone came up on the spot with an elegant algorithm and showed me how it would work with short, long, and invalid characters, I'd hire them. You can always *learn* new stupid Perl tricks, but quick-on-your-feet type of thinking is something that's hard to find.

I learned the reverse string trick a long time ago when someone asked me the same question in an interview. I looked it up and found it in the FAQ and realized I did it *wrong*. I've been using Perl for almost 20 years and I can't think of a time I had ever had to reverse a Perl string.

Comment: perltutorial.org is [not recommended](http://perl-tutorial.org/rejected/), all info there is questionable [by association](http://enwp.org/Association_fallacy). SO answers should cite authoritative, high-quality resources.

Comment: Processes often can only access a fraction of computer's memory, so you might be limited to far less than the computer's memory.

Comment: @daxim - I remember reading something similar in the Camel Book, but couldn't find it. I found a similar statement to the above in Perlmonk, but there's no reference there either. Maybe the correct answer should have been _Way longer than you probably will ever need, so don't worry about it._.

Comment: @ikegami - The maximum length really is a red herring. There will never be a time in Perl where you have to worry whether a string is _too long_ in Perl. The novel _War and Peace_ contains about 600,000 words, or about 3,000,000 to 5,000,000 letters. You can safely store this entire novel in a single Perl string without any problems.

Comment: @David W., That's not true. I've known people who have run out of memory in Perl. The max is reachable.

Comment: @ikegami They maxed out memory on a single string? Yes, I've seen applications that max out memory, but not because a string itself was too long.

Comment: @David W., I said the limiting factor is memory available to the process (not system). On Win32, that's less than 2GB before you even start allocating anything. It would be trivial to fill that up, so one does indeed have to worry about memory limits in Perl when dealing with large amounts of memory.

Comment: @ikegami The OP asked a question about the longest string in Perl. The interviewer raised a red herring. There is a limit to the amount of memory available in Perl. The OS could limit the memory a single process can use below that limit. However, there is little chance that a string would cause that limit to be hit. Even a long novel fits easily in a few megabytes which is way less than almost any process limits. I don't disagree w/ you. I just don't think max string length is a relevant Perl question.

Comment: @David W., What kind of argument is "A book is ridiculously small, therefore you won't have problems." The conclusion doesn't now follow from the premise.

Answer (score 5):

Fundamentally, it depends on the amount of memory that your program (that is, Perl) can access.  If you've got a 32-bit machine, that's somewhere under 4 GiB.  If you've got a 64-bit machine, then the limit is probably larger, and depends on the virtual memory available.  There is no fixed limitation.

Comment: ok. So how can one create a long string or in other words, create the longest string possible for doing the testing ?  What I am not sure is that is there even a need to have a long string as one of the test cases.

Comment: @user238021: this *will* hang your computer. You got warned:  perl -e 'print scalar reverse a.."z"x999'